# how do i render text put into a django textfield with a its original format?

Tags: django, django-templates

im building a site with django and i would like to output some text that I put into a text field from my model but when i do so in the html it loses all the form that i give it (spacing and new lines, etc.) does anyone have a solution?.

so instead of coming out as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cKpw.png)
it comes out as just a line without the proper spacing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFSIq.png)

EDIT:
in my html

```
 <div class="content">{{program.render_text}}</div>
```

in my models.py

```
class Program(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    course = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    purpose = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    help_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    inputvariables = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=1000)
    inputExtras = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=1000)

    program_file_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    function_to_call = models.ManyToManyField("Functions", related_name="functions")

    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def render_text(self, context=None):
        template = Template(self.help_text)
        context = context or {}
        context["object"] = self
        return template.render(Context(context))
```

Comment: Please share your code, in that way more people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to display the text as HTML so you can just type in the HTML in the text field and pass it on using `{{obj.property|safe}}` although you have to be careful what you put in the text field. As I am guessing, it could be a security problem, but that's not that relevant to my project right now.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is to be rendered in html I think it should work:

```
<pre>{{obj.property_data}}</pre>
```

Let me know if is what you are looking for.